# Acessing style information of TimeObject and DateObject DisplayForm

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, date-and-time, stylesheet, style

The two functions `TimeObject` and `DateObject` (both introduced in version 10) feature neat `DisplayForm`s:

```
TimeObject[0]
DateObject[0]
```

[image: Blockquote]

Custom content can be output in the same form using the `DisplayForm` of the `TemplateBox`es associated with the objects:

```
DisplayForm@TemplateBox[{"Foo"}, "TimeObject", Editable -> False]
DisplayForm@TemplateBox[{"Bar"}, "DateObject", Editable -> False]
```

[image: Blockquote]

---

## Question:

Is there a way to acces the style options internally used for creating this output? I am interested in frame color, frame thickness, rounding radius, font, font color etc. Furthermore, is there a way to acces the cute little icons representing the clock and calendar (as an image or symbol)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can get these information using

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "TimeObject", "TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction"}]
```

and

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "DateObject", "TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction"}]
```

The icons are

```
FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "TimeObjectIcon"] // ToExpression
```

and

```
FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "DateObjectIcon"] // ToExpression
```

---

Users working with version 10.3.0 might consider the following solution for accessing the icons:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "TimeObject", 
"TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction"}][[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] // ToExpression

CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "DateObject", 
"TemplateBoxOptionsDisplayFunction"}][[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] // ToExpression
```